Will a pointer to int have overhead?
Suppose I have a function foo which takes a parameter n and won't change said parameter, does passing it as pointer incur overhead?
Is there any reason to use a pointer in a use case like this?
extern volatile int bar;

void foo(int n){
    bar = n;
}
void foo2(int *n){
    bar = *n;
}


I don't see any reason to use a pointer in this case.

normally you only pass a pointer if (a) the thing it points to is big so that copying it will be time consuming, (b) if you want to change the parameter. in the cases above it makes no difference.

Yes, following the pointer is not a cheap operation (sometimes the compiler can optimize it, but it is overhead by definition).  And on 64-bit machines int* is generally 64 bits, but int is only 32

Is this plain curiosity? Or is there an underlying problem that lead to this question? If there's an underlying problem, then please ask about that directly. If it's curiosity please say that in the question.

I think you are using two separate questions, confirmed by the fact that you ask for an answer to the second question as comment on at least one answer. Consider focusing the question post on only one of them.

@Yunnosch I totally agree, I inadvertently did intertwine two questions. I should (have) separate(ed) them. I don't know which to remove, since there are answers for both of them now.

If you have answer to both questions then it is correct to NOT change the question anymore. Invalidating existing answers is a bigger problem. Nice that you understand what I meant however, take the insight along to the next question.

The performance of pass by value versus by reference depends on the ABI and calling convention. On most ISA, indirect access is either slower or just as fast as direct access. Also passing by value might lead to performance benefits if the ABI says it will do so though registers rather than the stack. An ABI might also pass pointers through registers, but the pointed-at data will obviously be in allocated, addressable memory, which is slower to access than registers.
(In some rare oddball scenarios, passing by pointer might be faster - lets say that we have an 8-bit CPU with an 8-bit address bus, but 16 bit int for example. Passing a pointer will then likely be more efficient both in terms of speed and in terms of memory use.)
But in this case performance also depends on whether the compiler is able to inline the functions or not. Since they are defined without static, the compiler will likely have to assume that another translation unit may call the function, in which case it will not be able to inline the function call. Otherwise in case it is able to inline, it would quite likely also produce the same machine code for both functions.
Also note that the volatile qualifier may restrict the amount of possible optimizations, but not in this particular example.

A somewhat common real-world example of skunky 8-bit MCU code optimization would be to take functions with many parameters passed by value and rewriting them to only pass a single struct by reference. This is a significant performance boost both in execution speed and in stack use.

wouldn't fetching the data from memory still be slower than passing at least some of the values via the stack?

@Semnodime Not sure what you mean with "memory slower than the stack", it's all RAM. On low- to mid range microcontrollers there's no cache and the penalty for reading from RAM vs a register is just a few clock cycles, since they are running on much lower frequencies than PC-like computers.

wouldn't fetching the data from memory still be slower than passing at least some of the values via registers?

Yes, using a pointer incurs overhead.
Look at this code
RISC V code:
foo:
        lui     a5,%hi(bar)
        sw      a0,%lo(bar)(a5)
        ret
foo2:
        lw      a4,0(a0)
        lui     a5,%hi(bar)
        sw      a4,%lo(bar)(a5)
        ret


I'd recommend to use godbolt's "short link" format.

Of course, it will have.
The pointer version will need to read the pointer variable and then read the integer value referenced by this pointer variable.
clang generated code (-Os, -O1, -O2, -O3):
foo:                                    # @foo
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + bar@GOTPCREL]
        mov     dword ptr [rax], edi
        ret
foo2:                                   # @foo2
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + bar@GOTPCREL]
        mov     dword ptr [rcx], eax
        ret


Please answer the second question also.
